Is there a better way to toggle values based on attributes?
I have several <ul/> elements which represent matchups in brackets. A person can be in multiple brackets. When a user hovers over a persons name, I want to highlight their matchups in other brackets.
When someone hovers over their name, in a <li/> element, I have it send an event to the <div/> containing all the brackets.
on mouseover or mouseout queue all send toggleHighlighted(bowler: [@data-bowler]) to <div.brackets /> end"

Then, on each <ul/> element, I handle that event and toggle font weight and text opacity based on the person being hovered over.
on toggleHighlighted(bowler) from <div.brackets /> 
  set local items to <li/> in me
  if items@data-bowler contains bowler
   then
     for i in items
       if i@data-bowler == bowler 
         tell i toggle  between .font-medium and .font-extrabold 
       end
     end
   end
   else
     tell items toggle  .text-opacity-25
  end
end

This works, but feels very clunky. In particular it seems like handler on the <ul/> could be shorter. I've tried different things, but haven't been able to get anything to work. Any suggestions?
